# Hosting simple Python Flask Web Service on IIS

Tags: python, iis, flask

I am new to python, I am following the steps given on https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8 to host a very simple python Code on IIS (On WIndows Server 2012)

Following are the actual steps that I followed:

- I installed Anaconda, also installed Python 3.6 on my server
- I Installed https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/
- Created an application on IIS, added Default App Pool
- Added Module Mapping with FastCgiModule and named it "FlaskHandler"
- It did not create a FastCgi settings at the server level so I added it myself. Note: I am not sure if FastCgi settings needed at server level IIS seetings or at Application level (I do not see FastCgi Settings) at app level IIS configuration.

*test.py*

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def mylist():
    my_json_string = json.dumps({'key1': 'Ram', 'key2': 'val2'})  
    return my_json_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

*web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Python" path="*.py" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe %s %s" resourceType="File" />
            <add name="FlaskHandler" path="*." verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

When I run the website in browser as http://localhost/test/ I get this:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: You forget to mention the port. In the above tutorial it is 8080 so try  http://localhost:8080/test. Thanks

Comment: @ Bilal Ali Jafri, I tried that but it did not work. Am i missing any critical steps?

Comment: By seeing your code again, route is / not /test. Have you tried  http://localhost:8080 only?. I also recommend you to see this blog. http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-flask-windows-development-environment-setup/

Comment: my IIS application test is setup in the default website so the url to the application that host this is either  localhost:8080/test or  localhost/test